# Laravel command executed in loop

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, redis

Are there any specific reasons for a command App/Console/Commands/ImportSecond.php to be executed in loop ?

It is launched at the end of the script of the job App/Jobs/ImportFirst.php :

```
public function handle()
{ 
    $file = $this->file;

    $extension = \File::extension($file);
    $name = \File::name($file);

    $lors = \DB::table('settings')
            ->where('parameter', 'mb_mode')
            ->first();

    if($lors->value == 'seg') {
           \Artisan::call('import:second', ["bid" => $bid, 'filename' => "$name.$extension"]);
    } 
}
```

The job itself is called by inject_file method from BController.php :

```
public function inject_file($bid)
{
     $name = \Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName(); 
     \Input::file('file')->move(storage_path() . '/bids/', $name); 
     $this->dispatch (new ImportFirst($bid, \Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName())); 
     return "OK";
}
```

To sum up :
BController.php dispatch ImportFirst job to Redis, which launch ImportSecond at last

**BController.php -> ImportFirst (job) -> ImportSecond (command)**

Laravel version : 5.1.26 - Queue driver : Redis

Comment: Can you post your job and controller file code. For all we know, it could be a loop in the job or a loop in the controller

Comment: public function inject_file($bid)
    {
        $name = \Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        \Input::file('file')->move(storage_path() . '/bids/', $name);

        $this->dispatch (new ImportFirst($bid, \Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName()));

        return "OK";

    }

Comment: This is the job's handle
public function handle()
    {
 if($list_or_segment->value == 'segment') {
            \Artisan::call('base:import_mindbaz', ["base_id" => $base_id, 'filename' => "$name.$extension"]);
        }
}

Comment: @AdelineMani-Rajan can you add the code to your question rather than the comments please :)

Comment: Yea, its not readable code in the comments